# Redirect String to STDERR Linux Command

Tags: linux, command-line, stderr

Let's say I have a `file` that contains a `string`. When I open it with `cat file`, I want the output of it to show in STDERR, not STDOUT. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cat file 1>&2

More info at: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html